# SQL query today

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$today = date('d/m/Y');

$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE DATE=$today ";
```

I need to show results that have today's date.

Comment: Ok? What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Please tag DBMS

Comment: What's your table structure? If it's a date format, the default format is `Y-m-d`. If the column really is named date, you'd probably need to put it in backticks (`\`date\` =`)

Comment: There's a native MYSQL function, `CURDATE()` - you can use that instead.

Comment: mySQL dates are 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: If you do pass in the date, you need to quote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are answering your own question :) you can always call php for the date as well, there you don't need to call the DB twice:

```
<?php
$today = date("m.d.y");
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

If `MySQL` use `CURDATE()`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE DATE = CURDATE()";
```

Comment: `CURDATE()` isn't a PHP function, so that last example won't work - unless you write the function on your own.

Comment: @Qirel thanks, edited :0

Comment: You can do `$today = date("Y-m-d");` and use that in a query, but then it becomes a string - which needs to be quotes :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it is MSSQL you use `GETDATE()`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE DATE=GETDATE()";
```

If it is Oracle you use `SYSDATE`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE DATE=SYSDATE";
```

Comment: How to display data only that have date from today?
Date in the database is in the format: 10/01/2017

        $today = date('d/m/Y');    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    
    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
    
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['date'] . "</td><td>" . $row['time'] . "</td><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['code'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] 
    }
    
    mysql_close();
        
    ?>


Thanks